# After prepopulating a PXFilter, how do I access data that the user "massages" in a dialog smartpanel?

Tags: acumatica

User "A" in the field enters data that must be scrubbed by user "B" to be compliant with corporate data standards.  For simplicity, user "B" reviews the original entry (stored in myDAC), and massages that data in a PXFilter (myFilter) view via a smart panel.  Upon clicking "ok" in the smart panel dialog, the data is processed into the many screens and tabs of Acumatica.

If the myDAC field is null, the user "B" data is filled into myFilter.Current.  If data is populated into myFilter from myDAC, then myFilter.Current does not contain the User "B" massaged entry completed in the smart panel. The result... the only scrubbed data that comes out the end is where user "A" didn't enter anything and user "B" did.  *Corrections* by user "B" are lost to the wind.

The only examples I have found in standard code are to ask for "new" user entry, none editing existing data.

In similar fashion to copyparamfilter in SOOrderEntry, my code contains:

```
WebDialogResult dialogResult = myFilter.AskExt(setStateFilter, true);
```

In the action that calls the dialog, user "A" entry is defaulted in above the myFilter.AskExt.

```
myfilter.Current.Descr = myDAC.Descr;
```

Processing of the massaged data is completed when dialogResult == "OK".  For simplicity of example...

```
InventoryItemMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<InventoryItemMaint>();

INItemClass itemClass = PXSelect<INItemClass, Where<INItemClass.itemClassCD, Equal<Required<INItemClass.itemClassCD>>>>
    .Select(this, myfilter.Current.ItemClassID);

InventoryItem item = new InventoryItem();
item.ItemClassID = itemClass.ItemClassID;
item.Descr = myfilter.Current.Descr;

item = graph.Item.Insert(item);

graph.Actions.PressSave();
```

I have seen the user "B" data contained in:

```
object filters = Caches[typeof(MyFilter)].Inserted;
```

...but I cannot determine how to extract the MyFilter data from the object "filters".

It is very important to retain the original User "A" entered data, but not the interim PXFilter data of User "B".  Using a smart panel for massaging the data simplifies the end user experience.  Using PXFilter ensures that the massaged data will not corrupt the original User "A" data.

How do I access the User "B" data in the PXFilter "myfilter" if the original data from User "A" was not null?

Comment: It works now, but I'm not certain that this is the right approach.
foreach(MyDac data in myfilter.Inserted) { myfilter.current = data; break;}

Comment: Back to the drawing board.  This broke when I upgraded to 19.109.0021, and I cannot find the user entered data by digging through the "locals" of a debug.